# Http Filters with Http Azure functions

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, azure-functions, azure-authentication

I'm writing a REST API using HTTP triggers Azure Functions. 
I need to implement something to block too many requests from the same user to prevent abuse.

Is there anything out of the box? 
If not, how would I implement something like

`AuthorizationFilterAttribute` class

to have

`override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)`

Comment: Was there an existing solution that you had for WebAPI?

Comment: @MikeS yes, it was using webapi2 and had the OnAuthorization to deal with the throttling per user.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-flexible-throttling) in front of your function. And you have the full freedom to define throttling per user.

Currently this is the suggested and easiest way to go.

Please do not abuse `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` to implement throttling. Plus, Authentication is already built-in in Functions - you do not have to explicitly define new one. [Here is example how to use Azure AD to secure Azure Function](https://peteskelly.com/secure-functions-aad-2/).

Comment: Can you please reference me to some step by step on how to configure that in API management? I'll give it a try. But that requires extra cost, any other suggestions for when on a budget ?